# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-svg:classpath'

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run my react native app.but when suddenly I get this error.
this my build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}
```

in addition, this is build.gradle file in react-native-svg/androdi project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to resolve this or undo this. Can anyone suggest something to fix this problem?

Comment: You've added react-native-svg? have you followed the steps mentioned here - https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#android, also can you add your app/build.gradle?

Comment: @NatiSholmanOskar yes.I have added and followed.